# How should I write the expression ($\tan\theta \sec \theta$)in terms of sine?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Write the expression $\tan \theta \sec \theta$ in terms of sine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$tan\theta =\frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$ and $sec\theta=\frac{1}{cos\theta}$

This means,
$$tan\theta\cdot sec\theta=\frac{sin\theta}{cos^2\theta}$$
Since, $cos^2\theta=1-sin^2\theta$,
$$tan\theta\cdot sec\theta=\frac{sin\theta}{1-sin^2\theta}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$ and $\sec \theta=\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$.

Now, 
$\tan \theta \sec \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} =\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\sin^2 \theta}=\frac{1}{2\;(1+\sin\theta)}+\frac{1}{2\;(1-\sin\theta)}$